# Google Play services Adds up additional process and causes additional memory consumption

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

i am using google GCM in an app , its working fine , but the problem is that it adds additional process (See **Screenpic** **Shows 2 process**) , named **Google Play services** (com.google.android.gms) which consumes about **20MB** which adds up with the app usage  to **28MB**

**Issue**   [Screenshot of the App Settings View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6eVx.jpg)

Note: i am not using **android:process** anywhere in the ***AndroidManifest.xml***

Even after closing the app still shows 1 service and 2 process

Where come the additional process ? Tested in multiple devices 
(Kitkat,Lollipop)

```
   <receiver android:name=".gcm.services.simple.GcmBroadcastReceiver"  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"    android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="com.tempapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".gcm.services.simple.GcmIntentService" />
    <service android:name=".gcm.services.listeners.InstanceIDListener" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**Gradle:**

**Module Level**

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

**Project Level**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha4'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you help around the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your app my not be the only one using Google Play services on your phone. More than half of the apps out there use GPS and it could be one of them. I don't think that is much to worry about.

Comment: sorry using GCM alone , its sure

Comment: your app may be using gcm only. but other apps on your phone may be using other GPS services.

Comment: sorry i cant get u,maybe other apps but why **Google Play services** named process attaches to my process and consumes more memory , my older app only consumes 8mb with gcm

Comment: @MickyC002 were you ever able to make a breakthrough on your question? Seeing the same issue, but Google Play Services takes up over 100mb.